# HTTP Error 403.14 - Forbidden on one URL

Tags: visual-studio, iis, asp.net-mvc-4

I am running a website using visual studio 2012 MVC .Net 4.5, IIS Express .
It was working fine on my local pc but suddenly a URL is not opening any more and gives me this error: HTTP Error 403.14 - Forbidden  http://puu.sh/1YWWm

and when i opened IIS on this website it gave me this error http://puu.sh/1YWY8 , how i can solve this issue, should i re install something, please tell me with steps if possible

Comment: Have you got a physical folder called UploadPhoto in your application? Where should visiting that URL take you?

Comment: i have a controller called uploadphoto, and it was working normal, just after a refresh i gave me this error

Comment: That second image indicates issues with your web.config file. Would you be able to update your question with its contents?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I found my bug, My website created a folder in the website root directory with the same name as my controller action path, seams that an error in my code did that.

Comment: I had a folder with the same name as the controller in the project folder. It was not part of the solution so I missed it at first. Deleting it fixed the problem

Answer (score 0):

It's probably a folder problem. It's that 95% of the time in this senario. check your root directory.

Comment: What you mean mate? I am also facing the same issue right now on MVC web application. Try to unchecked that as well nothing happened?

Answer (score 0):

I solved this problem enabling resources of .NET/ISS on Windows.
This options where unchecking in my machine.